# What is the difference between cv2.StereoSGBM_create() and cv2.StereoBM_create() functions for disparity mapping on opencv3?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencv3.0, disparity-mapping

I am trying to understand the disparity mapping functions of opencv I came across two methods cv2.StereoSGBM_create and cv2.StereoBM_create I don't quite understand the difference.

Also, what are the properties of the functions such as numDisparities or setSpeckleRange etc

Comment: For SGBM, see: [Stereo Processing by Semi-Global Matching and Mutual Information](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11134866.pdf). For BM, you should have some information and reference [here](http://www.diegm.uniud.it/fusiello/teaching/mvg/stereo.pdf).

Comment: @Catree are there more functions for disparity mapping?

Comment: there are more functions in `cv::cuda` here's the overview: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d6e/classcv_1_1StereoMatcher.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions of all the arguments are given at the bottom of the documentation page [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html)

In block matching or `cv2.StereoBM_create()` the disparity is computed by comparing the sum of absolute differences (SAD) of each 'block' of pixels. In semi-global block matching or `cv2.StereoSGBM_create()` forces similar disparity on neighbouring blocks. This creates a more complete disparity map but is more computationally expensive.

Paper that discusses ['block matching'](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/integrated1/konolidge_stereo_vision.pdf)

Paper that discusses ['semi-global block matching'](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.8897&rep=rep1&type=pdf)